# tkinter, entry value is not getting updated if used on toplevel window

Tags: python, openpyxl

I created a class to read data from excel file and add it to a tuple using openpyxl:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

class Excel_DataParse:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data_to_add=[]


    def abrir_workbook(self):
        self.wb=load_workbook(filename=self.file_path,data_only=True)


    def procesar_fila(self,num_fila):
        print("Procesando linea: "+str(num_fila))
        #valores por defecto
        case_consult=False
        case_escal=False
        Week_Rev=False
        case_reop=False
        SLA_meet=True
        case_consult=False
        case_escal=False
        case_reop=False
        case_comments="No"
        case_es_cons_date=""
        case_reop_date=""
        ws=self.ws
        print(type(ws))
        source=ws['D'+str(num_fila)].value
        status=ws['M'+str(num_fila)].value
        creation_date=ws['K'+str(num_fila)].value.date().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        if ws['N'+str(num_fila)].value == 'N':
            SLA_meet=False;
        case_no=ws['C'+str(num_fila)].value
        if source=="IPS cloud": #this probably should be moved to the excel_source.py file
            case_no=str(case_no)
            while (len(case_no)<8):
                case_no='0'+case_no
        case_geo=ws['I'+str(num_fila)].value
        case_cat=ws['E'+str(num_fila)].value
        case_pr=ws['G'+str(num_fila)].value
        case_gr=ws['H'+str(num_fila)].value
        case_topic=ws['F'+str(num_fila)].value
        working_date=ws['B'+str(num_fila)].value.date().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        case_min=ws['J'+str(num_fila)].value
        case_min=case_min*60
        case_hour,case_min=divmod(case_min,60)
        case_min=str(int(case_min))
        case_hour=str(int(case_hour))
        if status=='consultation':
            case_consult=True;
            case_es_cons_date=working_date
        elif status=='escalated':
            case_escal=True;
            case_es_cons_date=working_date
        if ws['O'+str(num_fila)].value == 'Y':
            Week_Rev=True;
        if ws['P'+str(num_fila)].value == 'Y':
            case_reop=True
            case_reop_date=working_date
        if ws['Q'+str(num_fila)].value!=None:
            case_comments=ws['Q'+str(num_fila)].value
        t=[source, status, creation_date, SLA_meet, case_no, case_geo, case_cat, case_pr, case_gr,case_topic,\
        working_date, case_hour, case_min, Week_Rev,case_consult, case_escal,case_es_cons_date,case_reop, case_reop_date,\
        case_comments]
        self.data_to_add.append(t)


    def mostrar_item(self,num_fila):
        i=num_fila-self.p_linea
        t=self.data_to_add[i]
        print("Source: "+t[0])
        print("Status: "+t[1])
        print("Creation Date: "+str(t[2]))
        if t[3]:
            print("SLA_meet? Yes")
        else:
            print("SLA_meet? No")
        print("Case Number: "+str(t[4]))
        print("GEO: "+t[5])
        print("Category: "+t[6])
        print("Product: "+t[7])
        print("Group: "+t[8])
        print("Title: "+t[9])
        print("Working Date: "+str(t[10]))
        print("Case hours: "+str(t[11]))
        print("Case minutes: "+str(t[12]))
        if t[13]:
            print("Reviewed on Weekly Meeting? Yes")
        else:
            print("Reviewed on Weekly Meeting? No")
        if t[14]:
            print("Case Consulted? Yes")
            print("Consulted date: "+str(t[16]))
        else:
            print("Case Consulted? No")
        if t[15]:
            print("Case Escalated? Yes")
            print("Consulted date: "+str(t[16]))
        else:
            print("Case Escalated? No")
        if t[17]:
            print("Case Reopen? Yes")
            print("Reopen date: "+str(t[18]))
        else:
            print("Case Reopen? No")
        print("Comments: "+t[19])



    def lee_datos(self,file_path,p_linea,u_linea):
        self.p_linea=p_linea
        self.file_path=file_path
        if file_path!="None":
            self.abrir_workbook()
            self.ws=self.wb["Time Report"]
            for i in range(p_linea,u_linea+1):
                self.procesar_fila(i)
        else:
            print("No valid file found")
```

When I call the method `lee_datos` from an instance of `Excel_DataParse` it works fine.

However when I call the same method by pressing a button from the GUI class:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button,Entry
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Toplevel
from tkinter import StringVar, IntVar
import getpass

from excel_source import Excel_DataParse

class DB_GUI:


    def __init__(self,master,excel):
        self.excel=excel
        self.sykes_uname=""
        self.sykes_pass=""
        self.p_line=0
        self.u_line=0
        self.master=master
        self.filename=""
        master.title("A Simple GUI")

        self.label=Label(master,text="Insertar casos en la base de datos")
        self.label.pack()

        self.log_button=Button(master,text="Ingresar login de Sykes", command=lambda:self.login_det_wind(master))
        self.log_button.pack()

        self.excel_button=Button(master,text="Buscar archivo fuente", command=lambda:self.excel_window(master))
        self.excel_button.pack()

        self.load_button=Button(master,text="Cargar datos de excel", command=lambda:Excel_DataParse.lee_datos(self.excel,self.filename,self.p_line,self.u_line))
        self.load_button.pack()

        self.test_button=Button(master,text="Probar", command=lambda:Excel_DataParse.mostrar_item(1084))
        self.test_button.pack()

        self.close_button=Button(master, text="Cerrar", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def close_top(self,window):
        window.destroy()
        window.update()



    def update_entry_val(self,entry1,entry2,window):
        if((type(entry1) is StringVar) and (type(entry2) is StringVar)):
            self.sykes_uname=entry1.get()
            self.sykes_pass=entry2.get()
        elif((type(entry1) is IntVar) and (type(entry2) is IntVar)):
            self.p_line=entry1.get()
            self.u_line=entry2.get()
        self.close_top(window)

    def excel_window(self,master):
        self.prim_linea=IntVar()
        self.ult_linea=IntVar()
        exl_wind=Toplevel(master)
        self.main_label=Label(exl_wind,text="Informacion sobre el archivo fuente")
        self.main_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.excel_button=Button(exl_wind,text="Buscar archivo excel", command=self.get_source_file)
        self.excel_button.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.prim_l_label=Label(exl_wind,text="Primera Linea: ")
        self.prim_l_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.plinea_entry=Entry(exl_wind,textvariable=self.prim_linea)
        self.plinea_entry.grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.prim_l_label=Label(exl_wind,text="Ultima Linea: ")
        self.prim_l_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.ulinea_entry=Entry(exl_wind,textvariable=self.ult_linea)
        self.ulinea_entry.grid(row=3,column=1)
        self.ok_button=Button(exl_wind,text="Acceptar",command=lambda:self.update_entry_val(self.plinea_entry,self.ulinea_entry,exl_wind))
        self.ok_button.grid(row=4, column=2)
        self.cancel_button=Button(exl_wind,text="Cancelar",command=lambda:self.close_top(exl_wind))
        self.cancel_button.grid(row=4, column=0)


    def login_det_wind(self,master):
        self.sks_login=StringVar()
        self.sks_pass=StringVar()
        log_wind=Toplevel(master)
        log_wind.title("Sykes Login")
        self.main_label=Label(log_wind,text="Ingrese su nombre de usuario y contrasena")
        self.main_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.uname_label=Label(log_wind,text="Usuario de Sykes:")
        self.uname_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.pass_label=Label(log_wind,text="Contraseña:")
        self.pass_label.grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.uname_entry=Entry(log_wind,textvariable=self.sks_login,show='*')
        self.uname_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.pass_entry=Entry(log_wind,textvariable=self.sks_pass)
        self.pass_entry.grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.ok_button=Button(log_wind,text="Acceptar",command=lambda:self.update_entry_val(self.uname_entry,self.pass_entry,log_wind))
        self.ok_button.grid(row=3, column=2)
        self.cancel_button=Button(log_wind,text="Cancelar",command=lambda:self.close_top(log_wind))
        self.cancel_button.grid(row=3, column=0)

    def get_source_file(self):
        os_user=getpass.getuser()
        doc_path="C:\\Users\\"+os_user+"\\Documents"
        self.filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=doc_path,title="Select file",filetypes=(("excel files","*.xlsx"),("csv files","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
        if not self.filename:
            self.filename="None"



root=Tk()
excel_cl=Excel_DataParse()
my_gui=DB_GUI(root,excel_cl)
root.mainloop()
```

It returns an error stating that

```
source=ws['D'+str(num_fila)].value
AttributeError: *'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'*
```

Adding the traceback:

```
<class 'openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet'>
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adolfo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Adolfo\Documents\GitHub\python_database\gui_class_example.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    self.load_button=Button(master,text="Cargar datos de excel", command=lambda:Excel_DataParse.lee_datos(self.excel,self.filename,self.p_line,self.u_line))
  File "C:\Users\Adolfo\Documents\GitHub\python_database\excel_source.py", line 119, in lee_datos
    self.procesar_fila(i)
  File "C:\Users\Adolfo\Documents\GitHub\python_database\excel_source.py", line 30, in procesar_fila
    source=ws['D'+str(num_fila)].value
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'
```

If I change the code to a different way to get a cell value:

```
source=ws(row=num_fila, column=4).value
```

I found the problem, for some reason *self.p_line* and *self.u_line* parameters are not getting updated, when I change the value on the toplevel window, see *excel_window* so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include the full traceback and focus on the actual code causing the exception.

Comment: How do I add the focus? I am sorry